# I have four tables and in each table I have multiple radio buttons now how can I get the selected radio button using javaScript

Tags: javascript, razor

```
<div id="tab_2_contents" class="tab_contents">
<div class="table-responsive">
<font style="font-size:large">
<table class="table table-responsive table-striped">
<thead>
1.The instructor set out the course objectives at the begining
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<label class="label label-success">
<input type="radio" id="radio" value="Poor" name="radio" style="width:20px" checked/>
<span class="lbl padding-8">Poor</span>
</label>
</td>
<td>
<label class="label label-success">
<input type="radio" id="radio" value="Fair" name="radio" style="width:20px" />
<span class="lbl padding-8">Fair</span>
</label>
</td>
<td>
<label class="label label-success">
<input type="radio" id="radio" value="Average" name="radio" style="width:20px" />
<span class="lbl padding-8">Average</span>
</label>
</td>
<td>
<label class="label label-success">
<input type="radio" id="radio" value="Good" name="radio" style="width:20px" />
<span class="lbl padding-8">Good</span>
</label>
</td>
<td>
<label class="label label-success">
<input type="radio" id="radio" value="VeryGood" name="radio" style="width:20px" />
<span class="lbl padding-8">VeryGood</span>
</label>
</td>
<td>
<label class="label label-success">
<input type="radio" id="radio" value="Excellent" name="radio" style="width:20px" />
<span class="lbl padding-8">Excellent</span>
</label>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table class="table table-responsive table-striped">
<thead>
2.The instructor communicated his/her ideas clearly
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<label class="label label-success">
<input type="radio" id="radio1" value="Poor" name="radio" style="width:20px" />
<span class="lbl padding-8">Poor</span>
</label>
</td>
<td>
<label class="label label-success">
<input type="radio" id="radio1" value="Fair" name="radio" style="width:20px" />
<span class="lbl padding-8">Fair</span>
</label>
</td>
<td>
 <label class="label label-success">
<input type="radio" id="radio1" value="Average" name="radio" style="width:20px" />
<span class="lbl padding-8">Average</span>
</label>
</td>
<td>
<label class="label label-success">
<input type="radio" id="radio1" value="Good" name="radio" style="width:20px" />
<span class="lbl padding-8">Good</span>
</label>
</td>
<td>
<label class="label label-success">
<input type="radio" id="radio1" value="VeryGood" name="radio" style="width:20px" />
<span class="lbl padding-8">VeryGood</span>
</label>
</td>
<td>
<label class="label label-success">
<input type="radio" id="radio1" value="Excellent" name="radio" style="width:20px" />
<span class="lbl padding-8">Excellent</span>
</label>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table class="table table-responsive table-striped">
<thead>
3.He/She encourages discussion during the lecture
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<label class="label label-success">
<input type="radio" id="radio2" value="Poor" name="radio" style="width:20px" />
<span class="lbl padding-8">Poor</span>
</label>
</td>
<td>
<label class="label label-success">
<input type="radio" id="radio2" value="Fair" name="radio" style="width:20px" />
<span class="lbl padding-8">Fair</span>
</label>
</td>
<td>
<label class="label label-success">
<input type="radio" id="radio2" value="Average" name="radio" style="width:20px" />
<span class="lbl padding-8">Average</span>
</label>
</td>
<td>
<label class="label label-success">
<input type="radio" id="radio2" value="Good" name="radio" style="width:20px" />
<span class="lbl padding-8">Good</span>
</label>
</td>
<td>
<label class="label label-success">
<input type="radio" id="radio2" value="VeryGood" name="radio" style="width:20px" />
<span class="lbl padding-8">VeryGood</span>
</label>
</td>
<td>
<label class="label label-success">
<input type="radio" id="radio2" value="Excellent" name="radio" style="width:20px" />
<span class="lbl padding-8">Excellent</span>
</label>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table class="table table-responsive table-striped">
<thead>
4.He/She competently answered participant's questions
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<label class="label label-success">
<input type="radio" id="radio3" value="Poor" name="radio" style="width:20px" />
<span class="lbl padding-8">Poor</span>
</label>
</td>
<td>
<label class="label label-success">
<input type="radio" id="radio3" value="Fair" name="radio" style="width:20px" />
<span class="lbl padding-8">Fair</span>
</label>
</td>
<td>
<label class="label label-success">
<input type="radio" id="radio3" value="Average" name="radio" style="width:20px" />
<span class="lbl padding-8">Average</span>
</label>
</td>
<td>
<label class="label label-success">
<input type="radio" id="radio3" value="Good" name="radio" style="width:20px" />
<span class="lbl padding-8">Good</span>
</label>
</td>
<td>
<label class="label label-success">
<input type="radio" id="radio3" value="VeryGood" name="radio" style="width:20px" />
<span class="lbl padding-8">VeryGood</span>
</label>
</td>
<td>
<label class="label label-success">
<input type="radio" id="radio3" value="Excellent" name="radio" style="width:20px" />
<span class="lbl padding-8">Excellent</span>
</label>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table class="table table-responsive table-striped">

<thead class="header">
5.Overall rating of the instructor

</thead>

<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<label class="label label-success">
<input type="radio" id="radio4" value="Poor" name="radio" style="width:20px" />
<span class="lbl padding-8">Poor</span>
</label>
</td>
<td>
<label class="label label-success">
<input type="radio" id="radio4" value="Fair" name="radio" style="width:20px" />
<span class="lbl padding-8">Fair</span>
</label>
</td>
<td>
<label class="label label-success">
<input type="radio" id="radio4" value="Average" name="radio" style="width:20px" />
<span class="lbl padding-8">Average</span>
</label>
</td>
<td>
<label class="label label-success">
<input type="radio" id="radio4" value="Good" name="radio" style="width:20px" />
<span class="lbl padding-8">Good</span>
</label>
</td>
<td>
<label class="label label-success">
<input type="radio" id="radio4" value="VeryGood" name="radio" style="width:20px" />
<span class="lbl padding-8">VeryGood</span>
</label>
</td>
<td>
<label class="label label-success">
<input type="radio" id="radio4" value="Excellent" name="radio" style="width:20px" />
<span class="lbl padding-8">Excellent</span>
</label>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table class="table table-responsive table-striped">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="javaScript:feedback()" id="feedback" value="Submit"/>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</font>
</div>

</div>
```

Here is my javaScript.

```
function feedback(){
var s = document.getElementById('radio').value;
alert(s);
}
```

for now I am checking which button is selected using alert but this is not working can someone help me where mistake. On click on button I would like to get all the selected buttons from all the table.Here I am trying to put feedback page into my application in which each question will have five choices to make each choice have radio buttons attach to it.

Comment: If your radio buttons are in a form, then you can get a collection of them using their name as a named property of the form. In this case, `var radios = form.radio` where *form* is a reference to the form DOM element. Loop over the collection to get the one that is checked, then get its value. You can't use *getElementById* with a *name* attribute or property, and you can't use it to get multiple elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `document.querySelector();`

```
function feedback(){
var x =document.querySelector('input[name="radio"]:checked').value;
alert(x)
}
```

[EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/r17ex6d0/14/)

Comment: What does that return if no radio button is selected?

Comment: @RobG one  From the supplied snippet one radio is always checked.
<input type="radio" id="radio" value="Poor" name="radio" style="width:20px" checked/>

Comment: Until someone "maintains" the code and forgets to have one selected by default, or a script deselects them all, or …. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can get a collection radio buttons using their name as a named property of the form, then loop over the collection to find the one that's checked, e.g.

```js
function getSelected(radios) {
  for (var i=0, iLen=radios.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    if (radios[i].checked) return radios[i].value;
  }
  return '';
}
```

```html
<form onclick="this.selectedRadioValue.value = getSelected(this.foo)">
  1<input type="radio" name="foo" value="1">
  2<input type="radio" name="foo" value="2">
  3<input type="radio" name="foo" value="3">
  <br>
  Selected: <input type="text" name="selectedRadioValue">
  <input type="reset">
</form>
```

If you wish to use the query selector interface, then you can use:

```
function getSelected() {
  var radio = document.querySelector('input[name=foo]:checked');
  return radio? radio.value : '';
}
```

Note that you must check the returned value first, since if no radio is selected, then *querySelector* returns null, and attempting to access the value property of null will throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

```
function feedback(){
var check = document.querySelector('input:radio[name="radio"]:checked').value;
alert(check);
}
```