# Trying to apply a value to a hidden input variable with JavaScript parsing

Tags: javascript, php, forms, paypal

I'm using a JavaScript function to get the amount to post. The only way I can get the `amount` is to parse the `item_name` input variable from the form. It works on Chrome, not on IE. By the way, it hooks to PayPal using PHP and MySQL.

```js
function ReadForm(obj1) {
  var holeObjectValue = obj1.item_name.value;
  var splitFields = holeObjectValue.split("$");
  obj1.amount.value = splitFields[1];
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post" name="form1" target="_self">
  <input name="item_name" type="radio" onclick="ReadForm(this.form, false);" value="Please Select from above $ 100" checked="checked" />Please Select from above $ 100<br />
  <input name="item_name" type="radio" onclick="ReadForm(this.form, false);" value="Please Select from above $ 200" checked="checked" />Please Select from above $ 200<br />
  <input name="amount" type="hidden" value="" />
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: What's not working? Are you getting an error? Do you know where it fails?

Comment: Does not work in Internet explorer. I'm not to good with Java but trying. I add this php to see the variables at the top. 
    <?php 
       foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
       echo '<p><strong>' . $key.':</strong> '.$value.'</p>';
     }
?>

Comment: You have two radio buttons with the same name, so *obj1.item_name* returns a [*NodeList*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) of the radio buttons. NodeLists don't have a *value* property. If you want to get the value of the selected radio button, see [*I have four tables and in each table I have multiple radio buttons now how can I get the selected radio button using javaScript*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34848640/i-have-four-tables-and-in-each-table-i-have-multiple-radio-buttons-now-how-can-i). Oh, and you can't check both simultaneously.

Comment: This question was unclear. I tried to clarify meaning and improve readability. Syntax and typography matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things going wrong. In:

```
  var holeObjectValue = obj1.item_name.value;
```

since there are two radio buttons with the same name, that returns a NodeList which doesn't have a *vlaue* property. To get the value of the selected radio, you can loop over the radios or use a selector:

```
var selected = obj1.querySelector('input[name=item_name]:checked');
```

In your markup you have made both radio button checked. It is the nature of radio buttons that only one can be checked at a time, so remove the *checked* attribute from one of them.

Lastly, you should not need to parse the value to get what you want, so make the value "200" or whatever, e.g.

```
<input name="item_name"  type="radio" onclick="ReadForm(this.form, false);"
  value="200">Please Select from above $ 200<br>
```

However, many browsers in use don't support such complex selectors so a looping solution is more compatible (and not a lot to write), so:

```js
function ReadForm(obj1) {
  var radios = obj1.item_name;
  var holeObjectValue = null;

  for (var i = 0, iLen = radios.length; i < iLen; i++) {
    if (radios[i].checked) {
      holeObjectValue = radios[i].value;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (!holeObjectValue) return;
  obj1.amount.value = holeObjectValue;
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post" name="form1" target="_self" 
  onsubmit="return false"> <!-- prevent submit for testing -->
  <input name="item_name" type="radio" onclick="ReadForm(this.form, false);"
   value="100" checked>Please Select from above $ 100<br>
  <input name="item_name" type="radio" onclick="ReadForm(this.form, false);"
   value="200" >Please Select from above $ 200<br>
  <input name="amount" value=""> <!-- show for testing -->
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

The last issue you have is that one radio is selected by default, but the value isn't written to the *amount* field if the user doesn't click on the radio. I'll leave that for you to solve.

Comment: I did need to parse but the loop is the solution. IE works now. I used php to create the radio selects:                                                                                           onclick="ReadForm (this.form, false);" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['item']; ?>  $<?php echo $row_Recordset1['price_10']; ?>" checked  />

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this and it will work in IE also :

HTML :

```
<form action="" method="post" name="form1" target="_self">
<input id="item100" name="item_name"  type="radio" onclick="ReadForm();" 
value="100"  checked="checked" />Please Select from above $ 100<br />
<input id="item200" name="item_name"  type="radio" onclick="ReadForm();" 
value="200"  checked="checked" />Please Select from above $ 200<br />
<input name="amount" type="hidden" value="" />
<input  type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Javascript :

```
function ReadForm() {    
   var selectedValue = 0;
   if(document.getElementById('item100').checked) 
        selectedValue = document.getElementById('item100').value;
   if(document.getElementById('item200').checked) 
        selectedValue = document.getElementById('item200').value;
   console.log(selectedValue);           
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/emilvr/v32e6vc8/

Answer (score 0):

The form is working. However in the page source the value assigned to the variable can not be seen.
It will be good if you `parseInt(splitFields[1])` before assigning.

Check the following code. I changed the method to `GET` and `action="xyz.php"` (Somefile).
When you click on `Submit` you'll see the parameters of `GET` request in the URL Box of your browser. There the hidden value is being set.

```
<form action="xyz.php" method="get" name="form1" target="_self">
<input name="item_name"  type="radio" onclick="ReadForm(this.form, false);" value="Please Select from above $ 100"  checked="checked" />Please Select from above $ 100<br />
<input name="item_name"  type="radio" onclick="ReadForm(this.form, false);" value="Please Select from above $ 200"  checked="checked" />Please Select from above $ 200<br />
<input name="amount" type="hidden" value="" />
<input  type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

I hope this helps you !